# How to set non-default quality gate for new sonar projects

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

We use jenkins, sonarqube 5.5, maven and git. When developers create a new git branch and push it, jenkins analyses the branch too, so the developers can fix everything before merging. To avoid this development branch analysis mixing up with the master branch analysis, jenkins passes the branch name into the analysis. The causes sonarqube to create a new project for each branch. So far that's ok.

But recently we switched from one default quality gate for all projects to different quality gates for projects under active development and projects which are just in maintenance.

So how can we tell sonar when creating an new project for a new branch which quality gate to use? Until some versions ago, there was a sonar.qualitygate property which could be set. But now this is deprecated. So what's the new way to define the proper quality gate for a newly created project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the rest api provided by Sonar.

Step 1. Create gate

```
        def result = ["curl", "--user", auth, "-X", "POST", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", "{'name':'" + qualityGateName + "'}", "https://yoursonarserver/api/qualitygates/create"].execute().text
```

Step 2 Bind project into the gate

```
    ["curl", "--user", auth, "-X", "POST", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", "{'gateId':'"+qualityGateId+"','projectId':'"+projectId+"'}", "https://yoursonarserver/qualitygates/select"].execute().text
```

About how to get the projectId and qualityGateId, you can use the following two apis

Get project ID

```
        String result = ["curl", "--user", auth , "-X", "GET", "-H", "Accept: application/json", "https://yoursonarserver/api/projects/index", "-d", "search=" + projectName ].execute().text
```

Get Quality gate id

```
        def result = ["curl", "--user", auth, "-X", "GET", "-H", "Accept: application/json", "https://yoursonarserver/api/qualitygates/list"].execute().text
```

The above two apis will get a list of ids, so you need parse them based the project name.

Br,

Tim

Comment: Hi Tim. Great info. But unfortunatly it does not solve my problem. The quality gate already exists. But the project is automatically created and analysed in one step by calling sonar analysis from maven. So I have no chance to bind the project to the quality gate *before* the analysis. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Forget to mention how we solve this problem, it is very tricky if you use the default branch mechanism. What we do is update the our project pom artifact id (default sonar project name) to something like abc-branch before it start to analysis with a simple shell script, so you have the opportunity to create the sonar project firstly with the rest api, then do the analysis, bind the gate....

Comment: Ah, I see. So the key to the solution is to create the project manually, right? Is there also an API call to create a new project, without already analysing it? Else when doing as you wrote "create the sonar project firstly with the rest api, then do the analysis, bind the gate" the binding to the gate would happen after analysis and so would affect the analysis.

Comment: Yes, you are right, what we do now is treating different branch as separate job, such as hello-dev, hello-master in sonar perspective. You can try with this api to create proj     curl -u admin:admin -X POST 'http://localhost:9000/api/projects/create?key=myKey&name=myProject'  for detail, pls ref http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392165